# Can't create NDB table in MySQL v8.0.28

Tags: mysql

I am creating a table using the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE interfaces (
    type VARCHAR(128),
    name VARCHAR(1024), 
    description VARCHAR(4096), 
    ikey VARCHAR(1024), 
    filename VARCHAR(4096), 
    syntax VARCHAR(4096), 
    hostname VARCHAR(256));
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'interfaces' (use SHOW WARNINGS for more info).
```

When I type `SHOW WARNINGS;` I'm presented with:

```
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                            |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1296 | Got error 738 'Record too big' from NDB                            |
| Error   | 1005 | Can't create table 'interfaces' (use SHOW WARNINGS for more info). |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

From what I've read on the white papers for MySQL v8.0 [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-cluster-limitations-database-objects.html), is that:

**Row size.  In NDB 8.0, the maximum permitted size of any one row is 30000 bytes (increased from 14000 bytes in previous releases).**

Don't I just simply add up the byte count in parenthesis of each column to see what my row size?
`( 128 + 1024 + 4096 + 1024 + 4096 + 4096 + 256 =  14720  )` Am I missing overhead? And if so, is there *REALLY* an additional 15280 of overhead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your default character set? It's utf8mb4 by default in MySQL 8.0, which means you count 4 bytes per character.

Therefore your row size is 14,720 characters * 4 bytes/character = 58,880 bytes.

utf8 is a variable-length encoding, so it's likely not every character will be a 4-byte character, but MySQL must assume that any or all characters in these strings *might* be 4-byte characters. Therefore it has to accommodate the maximum possible bytes per character when calculating the row size.

Comment: Thank you so much Bill.  You hit the nail on the head.